# Why do some browsers allow "invalid" character entities?

Tags: browser, rendering, entities

As far as I can tell [from the documentation](http://www.utoronto.ca/web/HTMLdocs/NewHTML/en_test.html), the semicolon is required as part of the syntax for entity reference.  So a non-breaking space must be `&nbsp;` not `&nbsp`.  However, it looks like Safari is the only browser that DOESN'T render entities without a semicolon.  Does anyone know why?  Both Safari and Chrome use webkit, yet Chrome renders regardless of the semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the **input** part of the principle of [Generous on Input, strict on output](http://tedwise.com/2009/05/27/generous-on-input-strict-on-output/).  Different browsers choose different measures of "generous".

Comment: True enough.  It's just irritating because I have a customer complaining that their code doesn't work in Safari, but works fine in other browsers.

Comment: At least in this case, you can probably advise them to be more strict on their output. Often browser incompatibilities are much hairier than that.